# Good jQuery Autocomplete that is not part of jQuery UI?

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

Is there a good alternative to jQuery UI autocomplete?

I couldn't find one on the internet. jQuery UI is far too big for just using the autocomplete, and I don't want to roll yet another autocomplete on my own.

**Answer**: jQuery UI custom build for just autocomplete is 23,052 bytes. [SO uses](http://cdn.sstatic.net/js/third-party/jquery.autocomplete.min.js) the original [Zaefferer version](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-autocomplete/) that was adapted into jQuery UI autocomplete. I guess if it's good enough for SO, it's good enough for me, forked it from [agarzola](https://github.com/agarzola/jQueryAutocompletePlugin) on GitHub.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/188442/whats-a-good-ajax-autocomplete-plugin-for-jquery. At least the (some of the) same answers will be given even though the actual question is a bit different.

Comment: How big was the minified custom build?

Comment: I agree with @Aleksi - it's 20kb after a custom build

Comment: I would list your edit as an answer. Zaefferer's plugin is 14,157 bytes, which bests jQuery UI (20,231 bytes) by 30% in terms of size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See https://github.com/agarzola/jQueryAutocompletePlugin/blob/master/jquery.autocomplete.js

Answer (score 6):

You can download a customized version of jQuery UI with just the components you need from **http://jqueryui.com/download**. Click **Deselect all components** then click the checkbox next to **Autocomplete**. The resulting minified js file is 20 KB uncompressed.

Comment: 23,052 bytes on my mac(hine). Core (4 files) + autocomplete. non gzipped.

Comment: It sounds like you are using the files in the `development-bundle` folder? The file `jquery-ui-x.x.xx.custom.min.js ` in the `js` folder should include everything you need in a single file.

Answer (score 6):

A Google search for 'jquery autocomplete' produced this DevBridge one (and all the others):

http://www.devbridge.com/projects/autocomplete/jquery/

This is also the most highly upvoted non-accepted answer in the [possible duplicate of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/188442/whats-a-good-ajax-autocomplete-plugin-for-jquery).

Comment: 7,187 bytes minified. Very nice!

Comment: So far the best. 2nd one I suggest is http://tomcoote.co.uk/code-bank/jquery-json-suggestsearch-box/

Answer (score 4):

The jQuery official plugin :

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/autocomplete

Select2 jQuery plugin that turn select into autocomplete input+list :

http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/

Chosen jQuery plugin, same thing but from a different author :

http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/

Jörn Zaefferer jQuery plugin :

http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-autocomplete/

Yahoo YUI :

http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/autocomplete/

Selectize.js (jQuery-based) :

https://selectize.github.io/selectize.js/

Twitter Typeahead :

https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/

Comment: I checked every link on this page, Select2 in my opinion is the best alternative.

Comment: @Kareem it's a matter of taste, I often prefer using non jquery based libraries (vanilla js is more light and fast), I think that's the case of Twitter Typeahead (I edited the answer to add selectize and typeahead)

Answer (score 0):

You can download a custom version of jQuery UI that only includes the autocomplete module:
http://jqueryui.com/download

Answer (score 0):

3 year old question this but since it comes 2nd on Google results for "best jquery-ui autocomplete alternative" I believe it's worth placing a link here for twitter's **Typeahead** implementation: http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/

Slightly annoying that you *might* need the Hogan templating engine to make it work (adding a few more kb's to the load), but if you invest the time to read the docs it will be worth it.

I replaced my "location lookup" jquery UI implementation after 30 mins of perusing the docs with the (simplified) code structure below:

```
$('.location_text_field').typeahead({

    name : 'locations',
    remote : {
        url : "/get_locations.php",
        filter : function (response) {
            return response.locations;
        }
    },
    template : '<p>{{{label}}}</p>',
    engine : Hogan

}).on({

    // When the user selects a location do something clever
    'typeahead:selected' : function (e, datum) {
       // Doing something clever here....
    },

    // Reset the cleverness above if the user changed
    // the text of the field manually on his own
    'keyup' : function () {
         // Reset cleverness
    }

});
```

... and it works like a charm.

Answer (score -1):

I was just looking for an alternative myself and found this

https://github.com/onigoetz/jquery.autocomplete

It uses jQuery, but not jQuery UI. It is size conscious, and it compatible with jQuery UI. Its "forked from agarzola/jQueryAutocompletePlugin" on github.

It may not have the backing of the well known jQuery UI implementation, but I tested it, and right now it seems to be everything advertised.

Comment: 404 page not found